# Chunk references with knitr::purl

Tags: r, knitr

It seems to me that `knitr::purl` does not handle chunk references. See e.g.

````
cat('
```{r label, eval = FALSE}
print("Second: hello world!")
```

This is first.

```{r ref.label = "label", echo = FALSE}
```
', file = "test.Rmd")
````

Now we process this both with `knit` and `purl`.

````
knitr::knit("test.Rmd", "test.md")
knitr::purl("test.Rmd", "test.R")

cat(readLines("test.md"), sep = "\n")

#> ```r
#> print("Second: hello world!")
#> ```
#>
#> This is first.
#>
#>
#> ```
#> ## [1] "Second: hello world!"
#> ```

cat(readLines("test.R"), sep = "\n")

#> ## ----label, eval = FALSE---------------------------------------------
#> ## print("Second: hello world!")
#>
#> ## ----ref.label = "label", echo = FALSE-------------------------------
#>
````

I am not entirely sure what `echo=FALSE` means for `purl`, but `echo=TRUE` does not work, either. `purl=TRUE` and/or `eval=TRUE` also produce the same.

Am I misunderstanding something here? Shouldn't `purl` just output the code that `knit` runs?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did as a workaround. For chunks that I didn't want to run, but wanted to include in the `.html` and `.R` output I specified `purl = TRUE`, e.g.

````
```{r label, eval = FALSE, purl = TRUE}
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rvs <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
  # ...
}
```
````

and then referred to them the usual way, but with `purl = FALSE` e.g.

````
```{r ref.label = label, purl = FALSE, echo = FALSE}
```
````

and then used this post-processing function to uncomment the sections that have `purl = TRUE`:

```
postprocess <- function(file) {

  lines <- readLines(file)

  include <- grep("^## ---.*purl = TRUE.*$", lines)
  empty <- grep("^\\s*$", lines, perl = TRUE)

  do_chunk <- function(start) {
    start <- start + 1L
    if (start > length(lines)) return()
    ## first empty line after start
    end <- empty[empty >= start][1]
    if (is.na(end)) end <- length(lines)
    lines[start:end] <<- sub("^## ", "", lines[start:end])
  }

  lapply(include, do_chunk)

  writeLines(lines, con = file)
}
```